# Best query to select nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two nested objects: RecruitmentUser that has_many RecruitmentUserStatusLog. RecruitmentUserStatusLog has an attibute called status. I want to select RecruitmentUsers that have RecruitmentUserStatusLog with status='processed' AND RecruitmentUserStatusLog with status='answered'. It can't be just one of them.. I tried some queries using ActiveRecord but I don't know if it is the most efficient way.. I tried this:

```
RecruitmentUserStatusLog.where(status: ['processed', 'answered']).pluck(:recruitment_user_id).group_by {|id| id}.values.select{|duplicate_id| duplicate_id.size > 1}
```

The select part is just for getting the occurances of id that are repeated (recruitment_user_id that has status 'processed' AND recruitment_user_id that has status 'answered').

But I think it's' much work and maybe there is a more elegant way to do this query.. I've searched but didn't find it.. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Starting out with StatusLogs is what I would do also, have you tried using `.joins(:r_users)` instead of where you go to `.pluck`?

Comment: Yes, to use join I need to do the inverse.. RecruitmentUser.joins(:log).. but I couldn't build the query to bring the results I want..

Comment: Not what I mean. What happens if you do `RecruitmentUserStatusLog.where(status: ['processed', 'answered']).joins(:recruitment_users)` and so on?

Comment: But RecruitmentUserStatusLog belongs to RecruitmentUser.. Is it right to use join in this case? Well, I tried and the result using RecruitmentUserStatusLog.where(status: ['processed', 'answered']).joins(:recruitment_users) was "uninitialized constant RecruitmentUserStatusLog::RecruitmentUsers"

Comment: Ah, it's probably singular. Try it without an S. (Notice the extra `s` on the class name Rails was looking for)

Comment: I have tried that too.. The error message: "ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'recruitment_user' was not found on RecruitmentUserStatusLog; perhaps you misspelled it?". The association in Log is belongs_to :recruitment_users

Comment: The correct invocation for [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) is singular. (Ps. http://api.rubyonrails.org/ can be your best friend!)

Comment: I got it working this way: RecruitmentUserStatusLog.where(status: ['processed', 'answered']).pluck(:recruitment_user_id).group_by {|id| id}.values.select{|duplicate_id| duplicate_id.size > 1}.flatten.uniq

I don't know if this is the most beautiful answer.. but it returned what I wanted.. the ids of the RecruitmentUsers that has logs with both status answered and processed.

Comment: I think the problem if you do that on a large scale, is that Ruby will have to load and process each record one by one. Which is why I'd recommend to use an aggregate approach where you craft your SQL query correctly from the start and then work on that. Unless, of course, it's a one-off project and not worth the optimization tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
user_ids = RecruitmentUserStatusLog.where(status: ['processed', 'answered'])
                                   .group(:recruitment_user_id)
                                   .having("count(recruitment_user_id) > 1")
                                   .count
                                   .keys

users = RecruitmentUser.find(user_ids)
```